# ¿Como recibir una notificación Push con la app cerrada? - Android

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, firebase, xamarin

Implemente un método en una app `Xamarin.Android` para que al agregar un documento nuevo a una colección en especifica de `Firebase Firestore` (si la app esta abierta o en background) envié una notificación local en el dispositivo del cliente correspondiente con un Listener de `Firestore`.

Les comparto lo que he logrado:

**De este modo (Listener):**

```
vListener = database.Collection("Usuarios")
                    .Document(IdDocUsuario)
                    .Collection("Notificaciones")
                    .OrderBy("FechaHora", Query.Direction.Descending)
                    .Limit(11)
                    .AddSnapshotListener(MetadataChanges.Include, this);
```

**Cuando se gatilla el evento (Cuando el Listener detecta un nuevo doc en la coleccion de Firestore):**

```
public void OnEvent(Java.Lang.Object value, FirebaseFirestoreException error)
        {
            try
            {
                var data = (QuerySnapshot)value;               

                if (data == null || data.Metadata.IsFromCache)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var snapshot = (QuerySnapshot)data;
                var Identifier = snapshot.Query.ToString();

//Validaciones propias de la app para no repetir la notificacion, tiempo y demas.

                    //Notificacion local:
                    string titulo, cuerpo;
                    titulo = "Notificacion";
                    cuerpo = "Hay actividad nueva...";
                    CrearNotificacionLocal(titulo, cuerpo);
                             

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                string LineErrorNumber = "Error en linea: " + Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7) + "\r\n" + "Error: " + Ex.Message; Crashes.TrackError(Ex);
            }

        }
```

**Metodo que lanza la notificacion localmente en la barra de notificaciones del telefono:**

```
public int CrearNotificacionLocal(string pTitle, string pBody)
{
    try
    { //Configuracion general de notificacion...

        if (!channelInitialized)
        {
            CreateNotificationChannel();
        }

        messageId++;

        //Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
        Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(cNotificaciones));
        intent.PutExtra(TitleKey, pTitle);
        intent.PutExtra(MessageKey, pBody);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(AndroidApp.Context, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, channelId)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .SetContentTitle(pTitle)
            .SetContentText(pBody)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            //.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(AndroidApp.Context.Resources, Resource.Mipmap.Icono3))
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.Icono3)
            .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);

        var notification = builder.Build();
        manager.Notify(messageId, notification);

        //return messageId;

    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        string LineErrorNumber = "Error en linea: " + Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7) + "\r\n" + "Error: " + Ex.Message; Crashes.TrackError(Ex);
        //ShowToast("Error en linea: " + LineErrorNumber + "\r\n" + "Error: " + Ex.Message, false);
    }

    return messageId;
}
```

**Todo bien con esto, el punto es que necesito que también lo haga cuando la app esta cerrada, lei que puedo lograrlo con Cloud Messaging, pero los videos que me encuentro solo sale la opción de Crear una nueva Campaña desde la Consola de Firebase, escribir el titulo, y el cuerpo y definir el target y enviarlo, y yo necesito algo mas "automático".**

¿Algún tuto que puedan compartir para hacer esto con `Xamarin`? Cualquier info servirá. Gracias.

Comment: esto se hace con [cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions)

Comment: cual es tu servicio ? lo tienes configurado en el Manifest? agregalo

Comment: @Jorgesys ¿Servicio? No recuerdo haber configurado nada en el Manifest. Solo lo que agregue arriba. El MainActivity dispara el Listener y el Listener dispara la notificacion local cuando un nuevo doc es agregado a la coleccion.

Comment: Editado para una mejor comprensión.

Comment: La clave está en delegar todo esto en Firebase. Tienes que hacerlo con Cloud Functions. Te haces una function que escuche cambios en el documento que necesites y envíe una notificación. En principio para mandar una notificación necesitas el id del dispositivo que se genera para GCM, pero en lugar de eso, yo lo hago por topics. El usuario se suscribe a un topic con un nombre tipo así: "mi_nombre_de_topic_${idusuario}". El Id de usuario entiendo que en la function lo conoce porque ya está en la propia ruta de documentos que tienes. Después, en lugar de mandar una notificación a un único usuario,

Answer (score 2):

Tu puedes generar una notificación desde tu misma aplicación pero si lo que buscas es que automáticamente se muestre una notificación desde tu aplicación, se debe implementar el envio desde Firebase

[**Crear un proyecto de Firebase y habilitar Firebase Cloud Messaging**](http://Crear%20un%20proyecto%20de%20Firebase%20y%20habilitar%20Firebase%20Cloud%20Messaging)

Preguntaba si tenias algo configurado en el Manifest ya que es esencial, después de configurar tienes que habilitar el receiver:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
    android:exported="false" />
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

además debes agregar los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Debes crear una clase que extienda de `FirebaseInstanceIdService` la cual será la que obtendrá el token de registro del dispositivo (`OnTokenRefresh`)

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Firebase.Iid;
using Android.Util;

namespace FCMClient
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
    public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
        public override void OnTokenRefresh()
        {
            var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
            SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
        }
        void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
        {
            // Add custom implementation, as needed.
        }
    }
}
```

En la documentación puedes ver el proceso completo

**[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/firebase-cloud-messaging)**

[**Notificaciones remotas con Firebase Cloud Messaging**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows)

Comment: Muy buen tutorial, super bien explicado. Ya lo habia leido, lo volvi a probar y efectivamente recibo la notificacion de prueba. Solo tengo 2 problemas con esto: 1. A como mencione en el post original, este metodo necesita que envie un mensaje de prueba desde la consola, y yo necesito esto automático (que Firebase lo haga solo al agregar un doc). ¿Como gatillo automaticamente desde Firebase? No logro comprender esa parte y capaz este implícito. 2. La prueba solo funciona con la app en background (ejecuto la app y presiono el icono de Home. ¿Que pasa cuando la app esta cerrada? (Ejemplo como Fb)